# Extend the expiration date of an oauth_access_token in Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I use Laravel Passport for an API based web application (Vue frontend, Laravel API backend). The oauth_access_token is created with an expiration date of +60 minutes. This period needs to extend with every server interaction (so always +60 minutes from now), to prevent users from logging out while they're active.

Is there any way I can configure this using Laravel's native Passport functions?

Comment: ```Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinute(30)); ``` you can put it in boot method in AuthServiceProvider

Comment: That's already there, and that doesn't get called for every request.

Comment: It'll generate a token with 30 min expiry time. It's not going to get called for every request, it's going to get called when you trying to create a new token for the client.

Comment: Yeah, so that's not what I want - or I misunderstand you. That exact code is already present in AuthServiceProvider::boot and generates a token with an expiry date of +60 minutes, but I want to have that token extended with every server interaction, not just on creation.

Comment: So you need a token with infinite time, because if the request enter the server every hour the token will never get expired. I mean the way you want it. I have not done such a thing before. But you can either create a new token on every new request or create a token with a long expiry time.

Comment: No, it's more akin to a session. Do nothing and refresh after 60 minutes -> expired / logged out. Keep going and the token validity extends and you stay logged in.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

A solution without using Password functions is just to get the token from the Auth::user() and updating its expiry date.

I have one single Controller method that the frontend calls for every page, and I can simply add the following code there:

```
$token = Auth::user()->token();
$token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60);
$token->save();
```

I'd like a more 'native' solution, but otherwise this works fine.

Comment: I take it you figured out that this doesn't work? Im trying to do something similar. But a JWT has a signature, and you can't just change the token expiry in the DB. the JWT expiry is in the token itself and therefore it won't change. Additionally you can't change the expiry in the JWT as it has a signature and therefore would fail to verify.

Comment: It does work, so I'll have to check if your JWT validation is actually correct.

Comment: I meant our* not your